# fill_betweenでwhereを認識させたい

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, テキストファイル

plt.fill_betweenでgreenの部分しか表示されません。どうすれば意図したグラフが得られるでしょうか？ (-が入っているから認識されない？)
知っている方はぜひ教えていただけると助かります。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f1 = np.loadtxt(filepath1)
f2 = np.loadtxt(filepath2)

x1, z1 = f1[:, 0], f1[:, 1]
x2, z2 = f2[:, 0], f2[:, 1]

##
plt.xlabel('X') # x軸のラベル
plt.ylabel('Z') # y軸のラベル
plt.plot(x1, z1, color="Black", alpha=0.8, linewidth=4.0, label="data1")
plt.plot(x2, z2, color="White", alpha=0.8, linewidth=4.0, label="data2")
plt.legend()
plt.fill_between(x1, z1, z2, where=z2>=z1, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)
plt.fill_between(x1, z1, z2, where=z2<=z1, facecolor='red',   interpolate=True)

# その他，描画用オプション
plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10) 
plt.ylim([-21.62, -21.46])
plt.grid(True) #グラフの枠を作成
plt.savefig("cm.png")
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

txtの中身は `(x, z)` の二次元配列です。

真のデータ

```
16.8180 -21.4740
17.0484 -21.6070
17.2787 -21.4740
17.4480 -21.4740
17.6784 -21.6070
17.9087 -21.4740
18.0780 -21.4740
18.3084 -21.6070
18.5387 -21.4740
18.7080 -21.4740
18.9384 -21.6070
19.1687 -21.4740
19.3380 -21.4740
19.5684 -21.6070
19.7987 -21.4740
```

一部回転B

```
16.8180 -21.4740
17.0484 -21.5070
17.2787 -21.4740
17.4480 -21.4740
17.6784 -21.6570
17.9087 -21.4740
18.0780 -21.4740
18.3084 -21.6070
18.5387 -21.4740
18.7080 -21.4740
18.9384 -21.6070
19.1687 -21.4740
19.3380 -21.4740
19.5684 -21.6070
19.7987 -21.4740
```

プログラムを訂正したところ次のようなエラーが表示されました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-32532a3f4e19>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Administartor/Desktop/いいべ.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administartor/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Administartor/Desktop/いいべ.py", line 46, in <module>
    plt.fill_between(x1, z1, z2, where=z2>=z1, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3031,) (15,)
```

Comment: これはつまりバックグラウンドカラーを設定する事と同義ではないでしょうか。`plt.gca().set_facecolor('red')`

Comment: 使われているデータに依存するのでは？ 試せるデータがあれば助言/回答も増えると思います。[Fill Between](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/whats_new_98_4_fill_between.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-whats-new-98-4-fill-between-py)

Comment: 内容追加しました。バッググラウンドカラーはこの場合関係ないです。　　解決していただきたいのは、x17.5~18.0の間の緑となっている部分です。本来ここは赤にしたく、whereで分けたはずなのですが、緑となっています。この部分を解決したいです。

Comment: 変ですよね。試しにデータのー符号を取って全部正の値にしたら、今度は両方とも赤色になりました。何が起こっているのか不思議です。

Comment: どうも `where` で比較している `z1_list` と `z2_list` が単なるリストである事が原因の様です。`fill_between()` を実行する前に、`z1_list = np.array(z1_list)` と `z2_list = np.array(z2_list)` としておいて、`plt.fill_between(x1_list, z1_list, z2_list, where=z2_list>=z1_list, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)` とすると(`z2_list<=z1_list` の場合も同様)想定通りに描画してくれる様ではありますね。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/221704

Comment: `... with shapes (3031,) (15,)` とあるので、「真のデータ」と「一部回転B」でデータの個数が異なるのではないでしょうか。fill_btween のドキュメントでも触れられていますが、データの個数と X の値(ここでは `x1` と `x2` の値)が一致しないと塗りつぶしはできません。

Comment: @metropolisさん。実際のデータは違います。そうですか同じ個数だからできたんですね。なら自分がしたいことはpythonではできないんでしょうか？

Comment: 個数を合わせればできるかと思います。3031行あるデータから、Xの値が一致する15行を取り出して、それを fill_between に与えれば良いはずです。

Comment: それだと自分の意図したグラフにならないと思うので、違う方法がないか調べてみます

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございました。
自分なりの解決策を模索してみます。

Comment: 逆方向の操作でも良いのでは？ 「真のデータ」のZ配列を2つ(Z1,Z2)用意して、「一部回転B」の「X値」が合うインデックスにあるZ2のデータを「一部回転B」のZデータで上書きすれば、両方 3031個のZ1,Z2配列が出来るでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

「一部回転B」データの「X軸」の値が同じになっていることが前提ですが、
コメントに書いた処理を質問記事のソースに組み込むと以下のようになるでしょう。

```
xw, zw = f2[:, 0], f2[:, 1] # x2, z2 を作業用配列に変える
z2 = z1.copy()              # z1 をコピーして z2 作成
for x, z in zip(xw, zw):
    idx = np.where(x1 == x) # 同じ X軸 値を探してデータを書き換え
    z2[idx[0]] = z

# ... 途中省略

# data2 の X軸 は x1 に変える
plt.plot(x1, z2, color="White", alpha=0.8, linewidth=4.0, label="data2")
```

Comment: @kunifさんご回答ありがとうございます。申し訳ないですが、それですと私の意図したグラフにならないのです（試しました）。真のデータがただ単に点と点を繋げているだけなので、現状としては真のデータグラフから座標を一部回転Bと同じ数だけ抜き取り（x座標が同じ部分）とすれば、出来ると思いますが、グラフに起こした座標を抜き取る方法がわからないので諦めました（あるのかもしれませんが）。もう一つは真のデータ引く一部回転Bとして、値がマイナスなら赤く、プラスなら緑といった形で数値でヒストグラムを作成するというものですが、私にはわかりませんでした。そういったことは可能でしょうか？　まだお時間があるようでしたら今一度よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: データの少ない方に数を合わせるのは簡単ですが、それでグラフが出来るか、出来たとしてイメージが合っているかは、確かに疑問ですね。出来るグラフに何を望んでいるかを明確化してから再質問した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: そうですね。したいことをもっと明文化するべきでした。当初の質問はできないことが分かったので、また別の枠で改めて質問したいと思います。ありがとうございました。