# matplotlibの表示について

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

現在10個のデータを同じ画面に表示させるプログラムを作成しました。
（x,z）の二次元配列です。askopenfilenamesでfor文を使えばもっと簡略化できることはわかっていますが、
tupleに関するエラーが出てしまうのでとりあえずこのようにしました。
以下のプログラムでエラーは出ませんでしたが…

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('微小山') #タイトル
root.geometry('400x200') #サイズ 横x縦

messagebox.showinfo('select','測定データ')
fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir1)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath1)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir2 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir2)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath2)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir3 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath3 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir3)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath3)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir4 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath4 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir4)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath4)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir5 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath5= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir5)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath5)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir6 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath6 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir6)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath6)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir7 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath7 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir7)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath7)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir8 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath8 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir8)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath8)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir9 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath9 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir9)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath9)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir10 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath10 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir10)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath10)


#list = [filepath]
#for i in range(len(list)):
  # list_item = list[i]

root.destroy()    
root.mainloop()

x1_list=[] # data1格納用のx_listを定義
z1_list=[] # data1格納用のz_listを定義
x2_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z2_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x3_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z3_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x4_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z4_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x5_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z5_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x6_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z6_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x7_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z7_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x8_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z8_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x9_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z9_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x10_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z10_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
#x11_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
#z11_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義

f1=open(filepath1) 
f2=open(filepath2) 
f3=open(filepath3) 
f4=open(filepath4) 
f5=open(filepath5) 
f6=open(filepath6) 
f7=open(filepath7) 
f8=open(filepath8) 
f9=open(filepath9) 
f10=open(filepath10) 
#f11=open(1, list_item) 

#data1読み込み
for line in f1:
    data1 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x1_list.append(float(data1[0]))
    z1_list.append(float(data1[1]))
#data２読み込み
for line in f2:
    data2 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x2_list.append(float(data2[0]))
    z2_list.append(float(data2[1]))

for line in f3:
    data3 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x3_list.append(float(data3[0]))
    z3_list.append(float(data3[1]))

for line in f4:
    data4 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x4_list.append(float(data4[0]))
    z4_list.append(float(data4[1]))

for line in f5:
    data5 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x5_list.append(float(data5[0]))
    z5_list.append(float(data5[1]))

for line in f6:
    data6 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x6_list.append(float(data6[0]))
    z6_list.append(float(data6[1]))

for line in f7:
    data7 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x7_list.append(float(data7[0]))
    z7_list.append(float(data7[1]))

for line in f8:
    data8 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x8_list.append(float(data8[0]))
    z8_list.append(float(data8[1]))

for line in f9:
    data9 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x9_list.append(float(data9[0]))
    z9_list.append(float(data9[1]))

for line in f10:
    data10 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x10_list.append(float(data10[0]))
    z10_list.append(float(data10[1]))

#for line in f11:
   # data11 = line[:-1].split(' ')
   # x11_list.append(float(data11[0]))
    #z11_list.append(float(data11[1]))

##
plt.xlabel('X') # ｘ軸のラベル
plt.ylabel('Z') # y軸のラベル

plt.plot(x1_list, z1_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data1")
plt.plot(x2_list, z2_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data2")
plt.plot(x3_list, z3_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data3")
plt.plot(x4_list, z4_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data4")
plt.plot(x5_list, z5_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data5")
plt.plot(x6_list, z6_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data6")
plt.plot(x7_list, z7_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data7")
plt.plot(x8_list, z8_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data8")
plt.plot(x9_list, z9_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data9")
plt.plot(x10_list, z10_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data10")
#plt.plot(x11_list, z11_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data11")

plt.legend()

plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10) 
plt.ylim([-21.62, -21.46])
plt.grid(True) #グラフの枠を作成
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
このように表示することができませんでした。
どうすればいいでしょうか？
このようなグラフです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/230068

Answer (score 1):

単純に、Y軸データが -21.62 ～ -21.46 の範囲に無いと思われます。
表示するだけなら、`plt.ylim([-21.62, -21.46])`をコメントアウトすれば出来るでしょう。

どういった範囲のデータなのかを把握して表示したい場合は、全部のデータの最大値,最小値を調べて、それに上下の余裕を追加して指定すれば良いでしょう。
こんな感じで最初のデータ：

```
min_z = min(z1_list)
max_z = max(z1_list)
```

2つ目以後のデータ(z2_list～z10_listにそれぞれ名前を変える)：

```
tmin = min(z2_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z2_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax
```

少し余裕を加えたY軸の範囲指定：

```
plt.ylim([min_z - 0.02, max_z + 0.02])
```

---

例えば[以前の質問のデータ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60348/26370)を基に少しずつずらして10個のデータを作って範囲を変えずに表示すると、以下のようになります。
[image: Fixed_Range]

データ範囲を取得して表示すれば、以下のようになります。
[image: Variable_Range]

Comment: 単純に範囲内に無いだけでした。追加のプログラムありがとうございます。