# 三次元で点と点を繋げるには？

Tags: python, matplotlib

下記の過去質問に関連したプログラムです。

[matplotlibの表示について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61505/19110)

10種類のテキストファイルを読み込んで、`[]` の格納して表示するプログラムとなっています。
データは今（X、Z）の二次元配列です。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('微小山') #タイトル
root.geometry('400x200') #サイズ 横x縦

messagebox.showinfo('select','測定データ')
fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir1)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath1)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir2 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir2)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath2)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir3 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath3 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir3)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath3)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir4 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath4 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir4)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath4)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir5 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath5= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir5)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath5)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir6 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath6 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir6)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath6)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir7 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath7 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir7)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath7)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir8 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath8 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir8)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath8)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir9 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath9 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir9)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath9)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir10 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath10 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir10)


messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath10)


#list = [filepath]
#for i in range(len(list)):
  # list_item = list[i]

root.destroy()    
root.mainloop()

x1_list=[] # data1格納用のx_listを定義
z1_list=[] # data1格納用のz_listを定義
x2_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z2_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x3_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z3_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x4_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z4_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x5_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z5_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x6_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z6_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x7_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z7_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x8_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z8_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x9_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z9_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x10_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z10_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
#x11_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
#z11_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義

f1=open(filepath1) 
f2=open(filepath2) 
f3=open(filepath3) 
f4=open(filepath4) 
f5=open(filepath5) 
f6=open(filepath6) 
f7=open(filepath7) 
f8=open(filepath8) 
f9=open(filepath9) 
f10=open(filepath10) 
#f11=open(1, list_item) 

#data1読み込み
for line in f1:
    data1 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x1_list.append(float(data1[0]))
    z1_list.append(float(data1[1]))
#data２読み込み
for line in f2:
    data2 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x2_list.append(float(data2[0]))
    z2_list.append(float(data2[1]))

for line in f3:
    data3 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x3_list.append(float(data3[0]))
    z3_list.append(float(data3[1]))

for line in f4:
    data4 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x4_list.append(float(data4[0]))
    z4_list.append(float(data4[1]))

for line in f5:
    data5 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x5_list.append(float(data5[0]))
    z5_list.append(float(data5[1]))

for line in f6:
    data6 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x6_list.append(float(data6[0]))
    z6_list.append(float(data6[1]))

for line in f7:
    data7 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x7_list.append(float(data7[0]))
    z7_list.append(float(data7[1]))

for line in f8:
    data8 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x8_list.append(float(data8[0]))
    z8_list.append(float(data8[1]))

for line in f9:
    data9 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x9_list.append(float(data9[0]))
    z9_list.append(float(data9[1]))

for line in f10:
    data10 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x10_list.append(float(data10[0]))
    z10_list.append(float(data10[1]))

#for line in f11:
   # data11 = line[:-1].split(' ')
   # x11_list.append(float(data11[0]))
    #z11_list.append(float(data11[1]))

min_z = min(z1_list)
max_z = max(z1_list)

tmin = min(z2_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z2_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z3_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z3_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z4_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z4_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z5_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z5_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z6_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z6_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z7_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z7_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z8_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z8_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z9_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z9_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z10_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z10_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

#tmin = min(z11_list)
#if tmin < min_z:
#    min_z = tmin

#tmax = max(z11_list)
#if tmax > max_z:
 #   max_z = tmax


##
plt.xlabel('X') # ｘ軸のラベル
plt.ylabel('Z') # y軸のラベル

plt.plot(x1_list, z1_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data1")
plt.plot(x2_list, z2_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data2")
plt.plot(x3_list, z3_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data3")
plt.plot(x4_list, z4_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data4")
plt.plot(x5_list, z5_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data5")
plt.plot(x6_list, z6_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data6")
plt.plot(x7_list, z7_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data7")
plt.plot(x8_list, z8_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data8")
plt.plot(x9_list, z9_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data9")
plt.plot(x10_list, z10_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data10")
#plt.plot(x11_list, z11_list, color="red", alpha=0.8, linewidth=2.0, label="data11")

plt.legend()

plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10) 
plt.ylim([min_z - 0.02, max_z + 0.02])
plt.grid(True) #グラフの枠を作成
fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.6)
plt.show()    # 描画結果を出力する。必ず書く。
```

一例テキストファイルの二次元表示

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これらのデータを奥行方向に繋げることはできないかと思い、似たような事を質問されている方をみつけました：[jupyter python　アニメーション　点と点を繋ぐ線の作成](https://teratail.com/questions/202453)。
こちらの方のように動かす必要はないのですが、三次元は扱ったことがないので、どなたかご教授下さい。

実現したいこと

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。 [Python 2D plots as 3D (Matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22412813/9014308), [Stack of 2D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10302986/9014308), [How to plot horizontal stack of heatmaps or a stack of grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57502763/9014308), [Stacked 2D plots with interconnections in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41204076/9014308)

Comment: 参考文献の提供感謝します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようなコードでできます。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np

# サンプルデータを作る

x1 = [ x for x in range(5) ]
z1 = [ z % 2 + 0.0 for z in range(5) ]

x2 = [ x for x in range(5) ]
z2 = [ z % 2 + 0.5 for z in range(5) ]

x3 = [ x for x in range(5) ]
z3 = [ z % 2 + 1.0 for z in range(5) ]

# list にまとめる
xs = [x1, x2, x3]
zs = [z1, z2, z3]

# ここから描画
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', xlabel='X', ylabel='seq#', zlabel='Z')

# 青線を一本ずつ描画
for i in range(3):
    ax.plot_wireframe(np.array([xs[i]], np.float32),
                      np.array([[i + 1 for _ in range(5)]], np.float32),
                      np.array([zs[i]], np.float32), color='blue')

# 赤線を一本ずつ描画
for i in range(5):
    ax.plot_wireframe(np.array([[x1[i], x2[i], x3[i]]], np.float32),
                      np.array([[1, 2, 3]], np.float32),
                      np.array([[z1[i], z2[i], z3[i]]], np.float32), color='red')

plt.show()
```

`add_subplot` に `projection='3d'` を渡すことで 3D になります。これで得た `ax` に対して
`plot_wireframe` で線を一本ずつ描いていくと良いでしょう。

ただし、`plot_wireframe` は、[このチュートリアル](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)の Wireframe plots にあるような図を描くためのもので、従って、与えるデータは2次元配列です。
今回は1本ずつしか書かないので、1次元配列を1つだけ持つ配列、としました。

全部同じ色で良ければ別な書き方もできますが、横方向と奥行き方向で色を分けるなら一本ずつ描くしかなさそうでした。

[image: 描画結果]

---

追記。

同じ色で良いのでしたら、以下のように書けます。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np

# サンプルデータ

x1 = [ x for x in range(5) ]
z1 = [ z % 2 + 0.0 for z in range(5) ]

x2 = [ x for x in range(5) ]
z2 = [ z % 2 + 0.5 for z in range(5) ]

x3 = [ x for x in range(5) ]
z3 = [ z % 2 + 1.0 for z in range(5) ]

# list にまとめる
xs = [x1, x2, x3]
zs = [z1, z2, z3]

# 2次元配列に並び替える
# X軸: 右向き (x_list)
# Y軸: 奥向き (系列番号)
# Z軸: 上向き (z_list)
X = [ [ xs[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(5) ] for i_y in range(3) ]
Y = [ [    i_y       for i_x in range(5) ] for i_y in range(3) ]
Z = [ [ zs[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(5) ] for i_y in range(3) ]

# numpy array に変換
X = np.array(X, np.float32)
Y = np.array(Y, np.float32)
Z = np.array(Z, np.float32)

# 描画
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', xlabel='X', ylabel='seq#', zlabel='Z')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

`X`, `Y`, `Z` はそれぞれ二次元配列です。
`i_x` は X 軸方向の何番目の点かを表していて、`i_y` は系列番号です。
二次元配列 `X`, `Y`, `Z` の値は、各点の X座標, Y座標, Z座標です。

これらの二次元配列を `ax.plot_wireframe()` に渡して、まとめて描くことができます。

[image: まとめて描く場合]

Comment: 返答が遅くなり申し訳ございません。違う色で書いたのは見やすくするためですべて同じ色で大丈夫です。masmは別な書き方もできるとご回答くださいましたが、他にどのような方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: @user36532 回答に追記しました。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。masmさんのプログラムを参考にプログラムをいじったらspyderでそれっぽいものが表示されました。事後報告ですが図として表示されるのでanacondaで開くとエラーで表示できませんでした。