# python list index out of range 表示

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

以前質問させていただいた内容です。
[三次元で点と点を繋げるには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61618/%E4%B8%89%E6%AC%A1%E5%85%83%E3%81%A7%E7%82%B9%E3%81%A8%E7%82%B9%E3%82%92%E7%B9%8B%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF/61625)

回答を参考にして以下のように書き直したところ、`list7` までしか認識されませんでした。
`for i_y in range(10)` としたところ、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
list index out of range
```

しかし `for i_y in range(7)` としたところ、`list7` まで表示されるようです。
どうすればいいでしょうか？

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Oct 29 15:19:41 2019

@author: Administartor
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('微小山') #タイトル
root.geometry('400x200') #サイズ 横x縦

messagebox.showinfo('select','測定データ')
fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir1)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath1)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir2 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir2)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath2)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir3 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath3 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir3)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath3)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir4 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath4 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir4)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath4)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir5 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath5= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir5)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath5)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir6 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath6 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir6)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath6)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir7 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath7 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir7)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath7)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir8 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath8 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir8)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath8)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir9 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath9 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir9)
messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath9)

fileType = [('テキストァイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプを指定
iniDir10 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
filepath10 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir10)

root.destroy()    
root.mainloop()

x1_list=[] # data1格納用のx_listを定義
y1_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z1_list=[] # data1格納用のz_listを定義
x2_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y2_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z2_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x3_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y3_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z3_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x4_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y4_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z4_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x5_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y5_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z5_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x6_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y6_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z6_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x7_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y7_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z7_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x8_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y8_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z8_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x9_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y9_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z9_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
x10_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
y10_list=[] # data1格納用のy_listを定義
z10_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義
#x11_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
#z11_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義

f1=open(filepath1) 
f2=open(filepath2) 
f3=open(filepath3) 
f4=open(filepath4) 
f5=open(filepath5) 
f6=open(filepath6) 
f7=open(filepath7) 
f8=open(filepath8) 
f9=open(filepath9) 
f10=open(filepath10) 
#f11=open(1, list_item) 

#data1読み込み
for line in f1:
    data1 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x1_list.append(float(data1[0]))
    y1_list.append(float(data1[1]))
    z1_list.append(float(data1[2]))
#data２読み込み
for line in f2:
    data2 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x2_list.append(float(data2[0]))
    y2_list.append(float(data2[1]))
    z2_list.append(float(data2[2]))

for line in f3:
    data3 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x3_list.append(float(data3[0]))
    y3_list.append(float(data3[1]))
    z3_list.append(float(data3[2]))

for line in f4:
    data4 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x4_list.append(float(data4[0]))
    y4_list.append(float(data4[1]))
    z4_list.append(float(data4[2]))

for line in f5:
    data5 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x5_list.append(float(data5[0]))
    y5_list.append(float(data5[1]))
    z5_list.append(float(data5[2]))

for line in f6:
    data6 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x6_list.append(float(data6[0]))
    y6_list.append(float(data6[1]))
    z6_list.append(float(data6[2]))

for line in f7:
    data7 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x7_list.append(float(data7[0]))
    y7_list.append(float(data7[1]))
    z7_list.append(float(data7[2]))

for line in f8:
    data8 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x8_list.append(float(data8[0]))
    y8_list.append(float(data8[1]))
    z8_list.append(float(data8[2]))

for line in f9:
    data9 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x9_list.append(float(data9[0]))
    y9_list.append(float(data9[1]))
    z9_list.append(float(data9[2]))    
for line in f10:
    data10 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x10_list.append(float(data10[0]))
    y10_list.append(float(data10[1]))
    z10_list.append(float(data10[2]))    
#for line in f11:
   # data11 = line[:-1].split(' ')
   # x11_list.append(float(data11[0]))
    #z11_list.append(float(data11[1]))

min_z = min(z1_list)
max_z = max(z1_list)

tmin = min(z2_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z2_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z3_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z3_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z4_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z4_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z5_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z5_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z6_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z6_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z7_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z7_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z8_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z8_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z9_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z9_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

tmin = min(z10_list)
if tmin < min_z:
    min_z = tmin

tmax = max(z10_list)
if tmax > max_z:
    max_z = tmax

#tmin = min(z11_list)
#if tmin < min_z:
#    min_z = tmin

# list にまとめる
xs = [x1_list,x2_list,x3_list,x4_list,x5_list,x6_list,x7_list,x8_list,x9_list,x10_list]
ys = [y1_list,y2_list,y3_list,y4_list,y5_list,y6_list,y7_list,y8_list,y9_list,y10_list]
zs = [z1_list,z2_list,z3_list,z4_list,z5_list,z6_list,z7_list,z8_list,z9_list,z10_list]

# 2次元配列に並び替える
# X軸: 右向き (x_list)
# Y軸: 奥向き (系列番号)
# Z軸: 上向き (z_list)

X = [ [ xs[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(6509) ] for i_y in range(7) ]
Y = [ [ ys[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(6509) ] for i_y in range(7) ]
Z = [ [ zs[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(6509) ] for i_y in range(7) ]

# numpy array に変換
X = np.array(X, np.float32)
Y = np.array(Y, np.float32)
Z = np.array(Z, np.float32)

# 描画
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', zlabel='Z')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)    
plt.show()
```

Comment: `filepath8`〜`filepath10`までのデータは`6509`個分存在しますか?

Comment: ご質問の主旨から外れますけれども、`x1_list 〜 x10_list` のサイズが 全て `6509` の場合、`X = [ [ xs[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(6509) ] for i_y in range(7) ]` などとなさっている部分は、`X == xs` となるので不要かと思います(`Y`, `Z` も同様)。つまり `X = np.array(xs, np.float32)` とできますが、`xs[i](i=0..9)` のサイズ(length)が異なる場合はエラーになります。

Comment: @OOPerさんご回答ありがとうございます。filepathのデータは全て6509個あります。

Comment: @metropolisさんコメントありがとうございます。全て同じサイズなので言う通りにしたところsetting an array element with a sequence.というエラーが表示されました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手元の環境で質問文のコードをrange(10)に変えて試したところ、正常に動作しました。

data8以降のデータに不備がある可能性が懸念されます。
行数は足りているとのコメントがありますので、行のどこかで何らかの形でスペースが欠損してzが足りない箇所がないかどうか確認してみてください。(スペースが足りない、全角スペースになっている、タブ文字になっているなど)
Tracebackを追記していただくと、原因が絞れるかもしれません。

data8の**行数が**不足している場合のTraceback例(ファイル選択のコードなどを若干改造しているため、"line 227"は実際の結果と異なります)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 227, in <module>
    X = [ [ xs[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(6509) ] for i_y in range(10) ]
  File "test.py", line 227, in <listcomp>
    X = [ [ xs[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(6509) ] for i_y in range(10) ]
  File "test.py", line 227, in <listcomp>
    X = [ [ xs[i_y][i_x] for i_x in range(6509) ] for i_y in range(10) ]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

data8の**列数が**不足している場合のTraceback例(ファイル選択のコードなどを若干改造しているため、"line 119"は実際の結果と異なります)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 119, in <module>
    z8_list.append(float(data8[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: @payaneko さん。ご回答ありがとうございます。すべてのファイルを確認すると一行足りていませんでした。合わせてると無事意図したものとなりました。ベストアンサーとさせていただきます。